# How to break circular dependency in knockout model subscriber?

Tags: knockout.js, circular-dependency

I am building models using Knockout. I have one parent model and couple of children. Each children has `obsevrable` (`computed` in working codem but it does not changes situation) `isLoading` which return `true` when any internal operation inside model processed.

Parent model has also computed `isLoading` which has subscriber. In this subscriber I want execute some code only once (I have special flag, it is ok). My problem is that this code changes somehow `isLoading` state of one child. And there I found that it does not raises parent computed changed.

How to bread this circular dependency?

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/202x4755/

**UPD**: Key point is to use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the circular update asynchronous. Because you have notify always, you should ensure that the update is necessary before kicking it off, or else you'll go into a perpetual update loop.

For this example, your subscribe should really be (only) on submodels()[1], but we'll assume you have other things going on that require it to be on the parent model.

```
function onStateChanged(value) {
    console.log('onStateChanged ' + value);
    // If second model finished loading automatically mark last model as loaded also
    if (!self.submodels()[1].isLoading() && self.submodels()[2].isLoading()) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.debug("Forcing submodel isloading to false");
            self.submodels()[2].isLoading(false);
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe your `onStateChanged` function to each submodel's `isLoading` observable instead of the parent's `isLoading` observable.

```
self.submodels().forEach(function (submodel) {
    submodel.isLoading.subscribe(onStateChanged);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Crimson/202x4755/1/

Comment: Not sure why this approach better then mine? Submodels could be added dynamically and potentially parent model could has a lot of submodels (20-30).

Comment: The submodel could do the subscribing when created if onStateChanged was passed to it, thus solving your dynamic concern. I believe this approach is clear in it's intent as it doesn't require any workarounds.